# Firebase with Twilio - SMS app in Angular4

Tags: angular, firebase, twilio, angularfire, twilio-api

I am trying to integrate Twilio with Firebase in angular4.
I followed https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sms-texting-with-twilio/ this documentation. Did all configuration with no errors. But when I opened the app in browser, I am getting below errors.

[image: Errors]

My data in firebase is shown below. I added it manually

[image]

below is my code

**pizza component ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Validators, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'pizza-status',
  templateUrl: './pizza-status.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pizza-status.component.css']
})
export class PizzaStatusComponent implements OnInit {
  numberForm: FormGroup;
  order: any;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
    this.order = this.db.object('/orders/testPizza123');
    console.log(this.order);
  }
  updatePhoneNumber() {
      this.order.update({ phoneNumber: this.e164 })
  }
  buildForm() {
    this.numberForm = this.fb.group({
      country: this.validateMinMax(1, 2),
      area:    this.validateMinMax(3, 3),
      prefix:  this.validateMinMax(3, 3),
      line:    this.validateMinMax(4, 4)
    });
  }
  /// helper to add validations to form based on min/max length
  validateMinMax(min, max) {
    return ['', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(min),
      Validators.maxLength(max),
      Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')  // validates input is digit
    ]]
  }
  /// converts the current form values to E164
  get e164() {
    const form = this.numberForm.value
    const num = form.country + form.area + form.prefix + form.line
    return `+${num}`
  }
}
```

** pizza component html **

```
<h1>Order Status: 
  <span class="tag is-large" 
        [ngClass]="{
                  'is-dark'    : pizza.status == 'submitted' ,
                  'is-warning' : pizza.status == 'cooking',
                  'is-primary' : pizza.status == 'on its way',
                  'is-success' : pizza.status == 'delivered'
                  }">

    {{ pizza.status }}
  </span>
</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Order Number: {{ pizza.$key }}</li>
  <li>Topping: {{ pizza.topping }}</li>
  <li>Price: {{ pizza.price }}</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<h1>Get Updates via Text Message</h1>
<form [formGroup]="numberForm" (ngSubmit)="updatePhoneNumber()" novalidate>
  <input type="text" formControlName="country"  placeholder="1">
  <input type="text" formControlName="area"     placeholder="916">
  <input type="text" formControlName="prefix"   placeholder="555">
  <input type="text" formControlName="line"     placeholder="5555">
  <input type="submit" value="Get SMS Updates" [disabled]="numberForm.invalid">
</form>
<p *ngIf="numberForm.invalid && numberForm.touched">That's not a valid phone number</p>
<h3> Updates will be texed to {{ pizza.phoneNumber || 'none' }}</h3>
```

** index js ** in firebase functions folder

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const twilio = require('twilio');
const accountSid = functions.config().twilio.sid
const authToken  = functions.config().twilio.token
const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);
const twilioNumber = '+91xxxxxxxxxx' // your twilio phone number
/// start cloud function
exports.textStatus = functions.database
       .ref('/orders/{orderKey}/status')
       .onUpdate(event => {
    const orderKey = event.params.orderKey
    return admin.database()
                .ref(`/orders/${orderKey}`)
                .once('value')
                .then(snapshot => snapshot.val())
                .then(order => {
                    const status      = order.status
                    const phoneNumber = order.phoneNumber
                    if ( !validE164(phoneNumber) ) {
                        throw new Error('number must be E164 format!')
                    }
                    const textMessage = {
                        body: `Current order status: ${status}`,
                        to: phoneNumber,  // Text to this number
                        from: twilioNumber // From a valid Twilio number
                    }
                    return client.messages.create(textMessage)
                })
                .then(message => console.log(message.sid, 'success'))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
/// Validate E164 format
function validE164(num) {
    return /^\+?[1-9]\d{1,14}$/.test(num)
}
```

Should I do any configuration here

```
const accountSid = functions.config().twilio.sid
const authToken  = functions.config().twilio.token
const client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);
const twilioNumber = '+91xxxxxxxxxx' // your twilio phone number
```

**UPDATE**

Now, I am able to update the data in firebase. the data is updating but I am not getting any messages to the entered mobile number.

Comment: Do you see anything in the log when you try to send the SMS? You should be either logging the message sid or error message. Also, are you using your regular credentials or the test credentials?

Comment: Tried with both credentials. No errors and and when console.log something from `functions/index.js`, no logs. And I tried sending message from Twilio website then I observed that my request is Succeeding with green color popup(message) alert but I didn't get any message to entered mobile number. And also number blocklist error in twilio console

Comment: Can you check your SMS log in the Twilio console and see if there is a reason the message wasn’t delivered? Either way, I’d probably bring this up with Twilio support at https://www.twilio.com/help/contact and include the message SIDS for messages that weren’t delivered.